# C++ Assertions that Can Display a Custom String with Boost or STL?

Tags: c#, c++, testing, boost, assert

I really want to be able to go: (in C++)

```
assert( num > 0, "The number must be greater than zero!");
```

In C# XNA, they have a method that does exactly this:

```
Debug.Assert( num > 0, "The number must be greater than zero!");
```

Is there some way to do this so that the runtime gives me a meaning full error not just "an assertion failed" error?

Comment: what do you want to print as an error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this in most any assertion:

```
assert(("The number must be greater than zero!",  num > 0));
```

Answer (score 5):

The runtime usually displays the expression that failed, so you can do something like this:

```
assert(num > 0 && "The number must be greater than zero!");
```

Which will not affect the logic, but the assertion failure message will contain a descriptive string.

In addition, this works without needing the STL or Boost.

Answer (score 3):

Use assert( num > 0 && "The number must be greater than zero!" );

Answer (score 0):

Using BOOST you can use their assert as described in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/utility/assert.html:

```
#include <boost/assert.hpp>
/* ... */

BOOST_ASSERT_MSG( num > 0, "The number must be greater than zero!");
```

would do exactly as requested.